# Getting values from dynamic listview

Tags: android, json, listview

So im getting values via json

```
   JSONObject json = new JSONObject(result);        
    if(json.has("message"))
    {
        message = json.getString("message");
   }
   else
   {
        for (int i = 0; i < json.length(); i++) 
        {
            suppliername = json.getString("s_name");
            suppliernumber=json.getString("suppliernumber");
            supplierid=json.getString("supplierid");
            HashMap<String, Object> data;
            data = new HashMap<String, Object>();
            data.put(NAME, suppliername);
            data.put(PHONE,suppliernumber);
            sampleData.add(data);
        }
    adapter = new MyCustomAdapter(getApplicationContext(), sampleData);
    lv.setAdapter(adapter);
  }
```

and this is my listener

```
lv.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int arg2,
                long arg3) {
        startActivity(new Intent(getApplicationContext(),
                    supp_details.class));
        }
    });
```

so what i want is when i click on the 2nd list item, it has to pass the 2nd values to the supp_details.class

Customadapter class

```
class MyCustomAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
    ArrayList<HashMap<String, Object>> data;
    Context context;

    public MyCustomAdapter(Context context,
            ArrayList<HashMap<String, Object>> data) {
        this.data = data;
        this.context = context;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return data.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int arg0) {
        return data.get(arg0);
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    public class Myholder {
    TextView name, phone;

    }

    @Override
    public View getView(final int position, View convertView,
            ViewGroup parent) {

        if (convertView == null) {
            LayoutInflater inflator = (LayoutInflater) context
                    .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            View view = inflator.inflate(R.layout.list_item,
                    null);
            convertView = view;
            Myholder holder = new Myholder();
            holder.name = (TextView) convertView
                    .findViewById(R.id.name);

            holder.phone = (TextView) convertView
                    .findViewById(R.id.phone);

            convertView.setTag(holder);
        }
        Myholder holder = (Myholder) convertView.getTag();
        holder.name.setText("name   : " + data.get(position).get(NAME));

        holder.phone.setText("Ph        : "
                + data.get(position).get(PHONE) + "");

        return convertView;
    }
}
```

this is my customadapter class

Comment: in your MyCustomAdapter class create the listener which is showing the data(suppliername,suppliernumber) Textview or edittext and get the vale from the listener ..

Comment: updated it with my customadapter class

Comment: Will you please elaborate this:  `...it has to pass the 2nd values to the supp_details.class`

Comment: 2nd values as in the second values from the json array

Comment: for example if you want to pass the phone num to yuor another Activity
... holder.phone.setonclicklistener(new Onclicklistener(){//Start the activity with the help of context and pass the phone number to put extra...})

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
lv.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int arg2,
                long arg3) {
        HashMap<String, Object> data = (HashMap<String, Object>) arg0.getItemAtPosition(arg2);
        Intent intent = new new Intent(getApplicationContext(),
                    supp_details.class);
        intent.putExtra("KEY", data);

        startActivity(intent);
        }
    });
```

Comment: throws The method getSelectedItem() in the type AdapterView<capture#1-of ?> is not applicable for the arguments (int), it tells me to remove arg2 from getSelectedItem(arg2).

Comment: my mistake. I want to write getItemAtPosition not getSelectedItem

Answer (score 0):

Take an idea from this:

```
listview1.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener()
{
     @Override
     public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int arg2, long arg3)
     {
             Addiction addiction = (Addiction) listview1.getItemAtPosition(arg2);
             String textview1 = addiction.getCatName();
             Intent intent = new Intent(StartActivity.this, AddictionDetails.class);
             intent.putExtra("cat_name", textview1);
             startActivity(intent);
     }
});
```

Make a little correction according to your requirement and re write this code in `OnItemClick()` method.